# Disable scrolling only down in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How I can disable only scrolling down if my condition is true.
I detect end of page with that code :

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
                alert("End Of The Page");
            }
        });
```

But sometimes this happened 2 or 3 times when I scrolling down. I want after end of page scrolling down be disable . How I can do it ?

Comment: Why? In normal case this is normal behaviour, you probably just have a CSS issue which should be fixed.

Comment: It is not normal to be able to scroll down past the end of the page. One might argue that by definition the end of the page is the furthest point that scrolling allows you to get to. If you are concerned about a blank area after the end of any visible content, please [edit] your question to provide more details about the HTML/CSS that you are using on the page.

Comment: I add to div new content on end of page. But sometimes content added double. Because I thing user scrolling down again. But I want  add and disable scrolling down when end of page.

Comment: And at the same time  I want scrolling up stay active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your JavaScript and did some modifications and now it will properly detect the end of the page.  Additionally, the code will only display the popup once.

```
flagTriggeredOnce = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        if (!flagTriggeredOnce) {
            alert("End Of The Page");
        }
        flagTriggeredOnce = true;           
    }
});
```

Example on jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/7x32gstj/